# Round doubles in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have double number in a format like `34.123456789`. How can I change it to 34.123?

I just want 3 digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can print it to 3 decimal places with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f",d]`.

You can approximately round it with `round(d*1000)/1000`, but of course this isn't guaranteed to be exact since 1000 isn't a power of 2.

Comment: first one did work for me ... :(
but maybe  just to stupid ... :D

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
#include <math.h>
:
dbl = round (dbl * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
```

Just keep in mind that floats and doubles are as close an approximation as the underlying type can provide. It may not be *exact.*

Answer (score 7):

The approved solution has a small typo. It's missing the "%".

Here is the solution without the typo and with a little extra code.

```
double d = 1.23456;
NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f",d];
```

myString will be "1.234".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make

```
34.123456789 -> 34.123
34.000000000 -> 34 not 34.000
```

You can use `NSNumberFormatter`

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setMaximumFractionDigits:3]; // 3 is the number of digits

NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:34.123456789]]);  // print 34.123
NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:34.000000000]]);  // print 34
```